# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMAltimeter", referenced in SKMaps

Tags: objective-c, skmaps

Recently I started having this error that I cannot fix.

I included all the frameworks i need in order to use Skobbler maps as intended and I have never again had this issue (and I did use SKMaps in other projects).

As I was searching around for the solution I noticed that before July 2014. there was another SDK for 64bit systems that I should use, but I see that now it's all sorted out from the Skobbler team.

Can anyone point me on what exactly could be a problem here?

**note:** I manually drag and drop SKMaps.framework in my project and did select "Copy items if needed"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are linking the `CoreMotion` framework.

Anytime you have linking problems, refer to the documentation first to see which dependencies it has (in this case, `@import CoreMotion`).

In case you are *sure* and ask yourself: "But I'm sure this symbol is in this framework!", as you felt when you said SKMaps.framework was linked and it should solve it, you can check if the missing symbol (_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMAltimeter in this case) is part of that framework.

On Terminal, you can run:

```
nm -g /path/to/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps
```

and check if the symbol is there.

To make it easier:

```
nm -g /path/to/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps | grep CMAltimeter
```

In this example, you wouldn't find it, because it's not part of it. But if you run:

```
nm -g /path/to/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion | grep CMAltimeter
```

You will see that the symbols are there.

If it's not there, it's because it is not part of this library/framework/version and you should find where it is.
If it **IS** there indeed, it means it is not being linked during compilation, and adding it to the link options should solve it.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Tell me how id you figure that out ?

Comment: @SteBra, the CM prefix is a clue. They usually refer to the name of the framework the missing code is in. Some of it is memory, if you didn't know CoreMotion existed you might struggle to guess which is missing.

Comment: Or you could just remember to Google Everything™.  That works too.

Comment: edited it to help you/anybody to solve linking problems in the future

Comment: Except you don't.  You have just confirmed what the linker is already telling you and it doesn't help anyone find out where the symbol *is* defined.

Comment: I believe it does. Many people don't know what symbols are and how to check if a library has it, so they learn it. Also, maybe you are linking a different version of a lib that should have the symbol, but it doesn't because it's the wrong version. OR you are linking a library that is in a different path than it should be. This case I explained would help to debug all that.

Comment: But it doesn't tell anyone that the symbol will be found in the `CoreMotion` framework.

Comment: The first step is to check the documentation, and look for dependencies, and clearly state that it is the CoreMotion framework.

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed out, link with the `CoreMotion` framework.

To solve these issues in the future, the formula is this:

1. Google `CMAltimeter`.
2. Top hit is [CMAltimeter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltimeter_class/index.html) (an Apple website).
3. Visit link and note that it's part of Core Motion framework.
4. Link in `CoreMotion.framework`.
5. Rinse, repeat until all such errors disappear.